# Unable to Destroy record. No association found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a new student learning about Ruby on Rails. For my current assignment I have to build a Question feature. Everything works but the deletion of a "Question".

I am trying to follow the Form Helper One to Many. Thanks for looking.

**Instructions**

> Complete QuestionsController and its corresponding views. Accept input for resolved in the Question form using a checkbox.
>
> Test your changes in the browser. Confirm that you can:
>
> see an index of all questions,
> view an individual question,
> create new questions,
> edit and update questions, and
> delete questions.

When I go to edit a question and then proceed to delete it with the checkbox this error is thrown:

*No association found for name `question'. Has it been defined yet?*

**Here is my console output:**

```
Started GET "/questions/1/edit" for ::1 at 2015-04-23 15:42:11 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#edit as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (No association found for name `question'. Has it been defined yet?):
app/models/question.rb:3:in `<class:Question>'
app/models/question.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:27:in `edit'
```

**questions_controller.rb**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :resolved))

    if @question.save
      flash[:notice] = "Question was saved."
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the question. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if     @question.update_attributes(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :resolved, :_destroy))
      flash[:noteice] = "Question was updated."
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the question. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter question title" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter question body" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :resolved %>
    <%= f.check_box :resolved %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :destroy %>
    <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit: added my answers.rb.

**answers.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: what is your answers.rb? You need to have the association in both directions.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Where is your destroy action in your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested attributes are for the *relation*. Your `Question` has many `Answers`. The point of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is that it lets you update "nested" associations from the parent model. The argument is the name of the association to accept attributes for. In this case, your questions should accept nested attributes for their **answers**:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

See the documentation, where the example class `Book` accepts nested attributes for `author` and `pages`. A `Book` does *not* accept nested attributes for a `book`, similarly your question should not accept nested attributes for a question.

---

As far as deleting the question, you cannot use `accepts_nested_attributes` to point a model back to *itself* so that [`_destroy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) will destroy the parent model.

You'll have to check for the presence of that attribute and destroy the record in your controller.

Comment: Curses, beat me by a mere 7 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` line in the `Question` class.

You wrote

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :question
```

but it likely should be

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
```

since that is the name of the `has_many` relationship. Rails is barking because there is no such relationship called `:question` inside the `Question` class. Your class should look like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You need in answers.rb

```
belongs_to :question
```

in order to complete the association

Comment: This is incorrect. You do *not* have to specify both sides of *any* association in Rails.